# Are servers asynchronous or concurrent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, asynchronous, concurrency

I'm a newbie in web development. I'm doing some interview prep and I came across a topic called 'concurrency'. Having read about it, in my understanding, concurrency is the performing/handling of multiple tasks at the same time. And asynchronous is handling of multiple tasks at different times/intervals.

So my question is, are servers asynchronous or concurrent?  (or are they both? since asynchrony can help us achieve concurrency ?)

Comment: Completely depends on the implementation/library, and it's possible for some to have a setting for both.

Comment: There is no generic answer to this.  Some servers process concurrent requests, some do not.  It depends upon the programming tools/environment.  Some servers use asynchronous I/O and some do not.  For example, a clustered implementation of nodejs/Express will use asynchronous I/O which will give the appearance of serving concurrent requests as multiple requests can be in flight at the same time and being worked on, but the clustering will give it full and real concurrency where multiple requests are actually running Javascript code at the same time.

Comment: right, thanks. i understand. so in some tools/languages,  there may be an implementation of both async and concurrency. and in some tools/languages only one is present..  So I'm guessing NodeJS is both async and concurrent right?